# Greenshot: Can no longer customise save location with dynamic dates in location field

Tags: greenshot

**Program:**  Greenshot v1.2.10 Build 6 (64 bit)

**OS:**  Windows 10 Home (up to date) 64 bit

**Problem:**   Up until a few days ago I was able to set a dynamic save location based on the current year and month, this no longer works and I am unable to save the settings.

Uncertain as to if this is user error (me), or a bug in the latest patch (Greenshot or Windows 10).

```
D:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\Greenshot\${YYYY}\${MM}\
```

OR

```
D:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\Greenshot\2018\${MM}\
```

Either the location destination will turn red, or I will be able to 'ok' out of the screen, however the screenshot will save to the desktop by default, the settings have not actually saved.

[image: Greenshot save location error]

I used to be able to have them save as

```
D:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\Greenshot\2018\2018 02
D:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\Greenshot\${YYYY}\${YYYY} ${MM}\
```

This no longer works.

[image: Greenshot save location error]

I am following the information that is in the program help (?) section, however nothing changes.

[image: Greenshot file location acceptable strings]

**Notes:**  The 'Filename Pattern' works, there has been no change, this has had no bearing on my save location.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patterns are applied to the field "Filename pattern" only. "Storage location" is considered a static "root directory" for saving screenshots.

However, you can easily prepend dynamic directories to the "Filename pattern", e.g. to dynamically create a directory for each day:

Storage location:

```
C:\path\to\screenshots\
```

Filename pattern:

```
${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}\${hh}-${mm}-${ss}
```

There's also an example in the help (?) window, but maybe it should be more concise.

Comment: thank you, that worked! User error on my end, I misunderstood the instructions. Things work as they once did, thank you. :)